# Parse hexadoku grid

Tags: c

I want to parse hexadoku grid like that one below, and put letters or spaces into `char hexadoku[16][16];`

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|             h | p   m   o     |     i   k     | n       f   l |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
.....
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Validating 1 and 3 line is easy just scanf like (1 - wrong input, 0 - ok):

```
(scanf("+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+%c", &n) != 1 || n != '\n')
(scanf("+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +%c", &n) != 1 || n != '\n');
```

But when I try to read second line with:

```
scanf("| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n",
        &hexadoku[line][0], &hexadoku[line][1], &hexadoku[line][2], &hexadoku[line][3],
        &hexadoku[line][4], &hexadoku[line][5], &hexadoku[line][6], &hexadoku[line][7],
        &hexadoku[line][8], &hexadoku[line][9], &hexadoku[line][10], &hexadoku[line][11],
        &hexadoku[line][12], &hexadoku[line][13], &hexadoku[line][14], &hexadoku[line][15])
```

Scanf fails with 4 of 16 chars written.
If i replace blank char with space and write it back to grid:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| h   |   p   m |               |               |               |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
...
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Any idea what's wrong with my code and how to parse hexadoku grid?

Comment: Are you sure that empty chars are spaces? I mean: could be that some of them are tabs '\t' chars?

Comment: Yes. I just checked input file in hex editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently want to use spaces in the scanf format string to require an exact number of spaces in the input. It won't work; scanf doesn't do that. You can really only use scanf when your whitespace requirements are looser than that.

One source of documentation about scanf ([Linux man page](http://www.manpages.info/linux/scanf.3.html)) describes it like this.

> White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string match any amount of white space, including none, in the input.

Since you're just extracting characters from fixed positions in the input, I'd read the whole line with `fgets` and then just pluck them out like this:

```
for(i=0;i<16;++i)
  hexadoku[line][i] = inputline[2+4*i];
```

Then run another loop to verify that all the other characters are what they're supposed to be (`'|'` and `' '`) if such verification is necessary.